# type traits for OpenCV data types

Tags: c++, templates, opencv, type-traits

I have a template method in which a Mat object is constructed. The type of this matrix depends on the template implementation:

```
template <typename T>
void createMatrixAndDoStuff(int rows, int cols){
// ...
Mat A(rows,cols,getCVtype<T>::value);
// ...
}
```

In this case I use a basic trait, `getCVType<T>::value` will return CV_32F if `T=float`, etc. I know this is silly, because I could have used `Mat_<T>(rows,cols)` and forget about using traits for this. But it made me think: **is there any available trait (or any template stuff) in OpenCV to infer type macros (CV_32F,CV_8U,...) in compile time from types?**

Comment: AFAIK there are not, but you could easily implement them your own.

Comment: @GermánDiago that's what I thought in the first place, I already implemented this `getCVtype` trait thingy :) But still, it is strange that no methods are provided in the OpenCV API, isn't it?

Comment: Well, the API was coming from C mostly, so I wouldn't be surprised if they don't provide that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

opencv do have the type traits for this task, it called cv::DataType, you do not need to create one by yourself

```
static_assert(cv::DataType<float>::type == CV_32F, 
              "cv::DataType<float>::type == CV_32F");
static_assert(cv::DataType<uchar>::type == CV_8U, 
              "cv::DataType<uchar>::type == CV_8U");
static_assert(cv::DataType<cv::Vec3b>::type == CV_8UC3, 
              "cv::DataType<cv::Vec3b>::type == CV_8UC3");
```